# I want MySQL to return a number but instead it returns a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use this code:

```php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "[censored]";
$password = "[censored]";
$dbname = "[censored]";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("disconnected");
}

$secret_token = sha1(rand(1,9999999999));
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) FROM `sessions` WHERE username = 'isOnline4'";
echo $conn->query($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) == 1) {
    echo "I am fairly sure you already have a secret token boi!";
    die;
} else {
    echo "Nope";
}
$conn->close();
```

And I was under the impression that `$conn->query($sql)` would return a number like 1, 2, or 3, but instead it is returning a row. I have tried several different kinds of queries but they all return tables or a table containing a number.

Comment: Show us your PHP code you use to execute your query and fetch the results?

Comment: Its normal, just use an alias `COUNT(username) as number` and use the alias in your array/object result `$result['number']` or `result[0]['number']` depending on your php code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JordanB-1337/b806c4c6b9e71703af83e8d2a21a851d

Comment: 1 is a number too

Comment: When you fetch from a query result you get rows, either multiple rows or 1 row. In the case of count you get 1 row.

Comment: @olibiaz Okay, I'll try that out. Thanks for the, like, instant response.

Comment: `"but instead it is returning a number"` - The examples you give *are* numbers.  Can you specify more clearly what the problem is?  And what this has to do with PHP?  What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: Sorry David, I misspoke. But I *think* I have my answer (haven't tested it yet) so I am not going to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object( mysqli_query(your_db_connection_obj , "SELECT COUNT(username) as n FROM `sessions` WHERE username = 'isOnline4'"));

echo $obj->n;
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you have to do, is change the query, like this

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) as number FROM `sessions` WHERE username = 'isOnline4'";
```

Then, in the if, check the alias "number"

Comment: That ended up giving me a "fatal error", see above.